# React JS react-router-dom results in 404

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am fairly new to React and am trying to utilize the react router feature. I am displaying Static pages on a TV screen pointing to a certain URL.

When in my Dev environment everything is working fine. When I enter the correct path it points to the set component. When loading it onto my hosting server and testing on a Live URL pointing to the desired path results in a 404.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './style/App.css';
import Header from './js/components/header';
import Menu from './js/components/menu';
import MenuTwo from './js/components/menuTwo';
import {  BrowserRouter as Router,  Route, Switch, Link } from 'react-
router-dom';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
   return (
     <Router>
  <div>
      <Header headerProp="maxwell's pizzeria" /> 
      <Route path="/" exact component={Menu} />
      <Route path="/menuTwo" exact component={MenuTwo} />

  </div>

  </Router>
  )
 }
}

export default App;
```

The webpack.config which I am also not very familiar with is as follows:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/build');

// Existing Code ....
var config = {
 // Existing Code ....
 module : {
  loaders : [
   {
    test : /\.jsx?/,
    include : APP_DIR,
    loader : 'babel'
  }
  ]
 }
}

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: is the path on the remote server the same as local test server? e.g. myserver.com/ vs localhost:8080/ or myserver.com/path vs localhost:8080/path, maybe you deployed your app to the wrong location: "You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json"

Comment: Your webserver is probably not configured correctly. It needs to serve your app on every route requested as your app takes care of the routing below `/` itself. If you request e.g. `/menuTwo` it will probably try to serve the page located locally on your server which is not existing. It needs to serve your app on every route, not only on `/`.

Answer (score 3):

First check your `homepage` entry in the `package.json`.

```
"homepage": "http://example.com/path/to/app",
```

then you may try some rewrite rule to point to your apps in the`.htaccess` file:

```
#Options All -Indexes
Options -Indexes
<Files *.php>
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php5
</Files>
# BEGIN My App Web-App
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  IndexIgnore */*
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /path/to/app/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule (.*) /path/to/app/index.html
</ifModule>
# END   My App Web-App
```

**EDIT**

And of course set the `basename` on the `Router`

```
<Router basename='/path/to/app'>
```